# Android DateFormat.parse(String) is parsing wrong dates

Tags: android, string, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm working on my Android app, but unfortunately I faced a problem which is not covered anywhere. The wrong dates are parsed, as stated in the title, my code sample is here:

```
EditText date_field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
String date = date_field.getText().toString();
DateFormat date_format = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
try
{
    date_format.parse(date);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please specify the date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't catch exceptions for input like "0.0.0" or "03.06.05" and so on. I've tried to use a handmade DateFormat like this:

```
DateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

but it also didn't help. Does anyone has any idea why is it parsing wrong dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DatePicker instead of an EditText for date entry.

XML :

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Android Docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Answer (score 1):

Conside using [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html). Some useful methods to avoid incorrect date input: **getDatePicker().setMinDate(millis)** and **getDatePicker().setMaxDate(millis)**

Example:

**UI**

```
    birthday = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.birthday);
    birthday.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int code = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            switch (code) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    DatePickerDialogFragment datePickerDialogFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment();
                    datePickerDialogFragment.setListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                            birthday.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", calendar));
                        }
                    });
                    datePickerDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DatePickerDialogFragment.TAG);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**DatePickerDialogFragment**

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(DatePickerDialogFragment.class);

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                listener,
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.add(Calendar.YEAR, -4);
        today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(today.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void setListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

In this example **DatePickerDialog** is wrapped to DialogFragment so it can survive on config changes (such as screen rotations etc). Also minimum date is set to not less than 4 years ago - you can change it however.